# Cannot push (or pull) from own private repo?

Tags: git, github

So I set up a private repo on Github about 10 minutes ago and I'm now trying to pull my README file, then push my files that I have now to it, but I seem unable to do so.  It keeps giving me a "fatal: repository not found" error when I try to do anything with it - I know the repository exists (because I just created it) and I'm using the https link, not the SSH, so what seems to be issue? I'm not sure what extra info I can provide as I know this is a very generic problem.

Comment: Does repository uri contains your username in `https://youruser@github.com/company/repository.git` format? It must be specified. At cloning/pull/push time you will be asked for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"fatal: repository not found" can mean:

- you don't have the right to clone it (wrong credentials, as mentioned, you can at least include your GitHub username in the url)
- or it doesn't exist (wrong case, like `github.com/Company/Repository.git` instead of `github.com/company/repository.git`)

Double-check those two elements, and you will be able to clone.

Obviously, `github.com/company/repository.git` is just a template name: you would replace "company" and "repository" by the right username and reponame.

https://github.com/epitone does exist, but double-check that there is a private repo created with the `Fright-Night` name.

Comment: I don't have a "company" in my url (as it is a personal repository) and the only link I've been using is: "https://github.com/epitone/Fright-Night.git" (the link provided in the repository itself) and I'm not sure how to check against the first condition, it's my repository so how can I not have the right to clone it?

Comment: @TaiM. I have edited the answer (obviously 'company' was just an example). Make sure your private repo is name "`Fright-Night`", and that you are using your `epitone` user name and password.

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't know why I couldn't figure that out myself but I appreciate the clarification.